# SQL Server 2008 setup error Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition on windows 7 and during installation it give error:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized
>   operation

Answer (score 0):

check your disk privileges - assume you are admin on the machine.

Comment: yes you are right it is problem of priviliges when i give premission as a amdinistrator in registry it installed without any problem.